# App submitted to Amazon AppStore is both "Status: Incomplete" and "Cannot edit application while in review"

Tags: android, amazon-appstore

Yesterday I submitted my application to the Amazon AppStore. I did not upload a video, because I haven't made one and it seemed optional, because I was able to submit the app without one.

Today I checked the app's status, it says "Status: Incomplete (Missing Multimedia)" with a link to the multimedia section whose video field says "Video < none uploaded >".

So I made a video, but I can not add it because it says "Cannot edit application while in review."

I used the "Feeback" link to send a message to Amazon, I might even get a reply, but do anyone already know a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few after notifying Amazon, the multimedia section became available, and I was able to submit the app properly.